# I cant find a solution for the error Uncought Error - undefined is not a function

Tags: typescript, react-native, graphql, expo, apollo-client

I am trying to run a react native project that is already working in another PC with same configuration an dependencies version!

The error I am getting says: "Uncaught Error - undefined is not a function"

This is error message on Android device emulator

[image]

This is my fragments.ts file:

```js
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

/* Trip */
export const LocationFragment = gql`
    fragment LocationFragment on Trip_Location {
        latitude
        longitude
    }
`;

export const TripAttachmentFragment = gql`
    fragment TripAttachmentFragment on Trip_Attachment {
        uid
        size
        name
        type
        url
    }
`;
 
export const TripFragment = gql`
    ${LocationFragment}
    ${TripAttachmentFragment}
    fragment TripFragment on Trip {
        _id
        logicalId
        startPoint {
            ...LocationFragment
        }
        endPoint {
            ...LocationFragment
        }
        startDate
        endDate
        status
        dropPhoto {
            ...TripAttachmentFragment
        }
    }
`;


/* Vehicule */
export const VehiculeLocationFragment = gql`
    fragment VehiculeLocationFragment on Vehicule_Location {
        latitude
        longitude
    }
`;

export const VehiculeFragment = gql`
    ${VehiculeLocationFragment}
    fragment VehiculeFragment on Vehicule {
        _id
        logicalId
        type
        qrcode
        mileage
        status
        batteryLevel
        city
        powerType
        operatedDate
        location {
            ...VehiculeLocationFragment
        }
    }
`;
```

This is my index.ts file:

```js
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { Trip, TripQueryFilter, VehiculeQueryFilter, Vehicule, } from "../shared/types";
import { TripFragment, VehiculeFragment } from './fragments';

export type GetTripsRequest = { request: TripQueryFilter };
export type GetTripsResponse = { CI_MGT_getTrips: Trip[] };
export const CI_GET_TRIPS = gql`
   ${TripFragment}
    query getTrips($request: TripQueryFilter) {
        CI_MGT_getTrips(request: $request) {
            ...TripFragment
        }
    }
`;

export type GetVehiculesRequest = { request: VehiculeQueryFilter };
export type GetVehiculesResponse = { CI_MGT_getVehicules: Vehicule[] };
export const CI_GET_VEHICULES = gql`
   ${VehiculeFragment}
    query getVehicules($request: VehiculeQueryFilter) {
        CI_MGT_getVehicules(request: $request) {
            ...VehiculeFragment
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: Are you sure `@apollo/client` exists on your second machine?  If `gql` was undefined, this is the error you'd get.